# hooks/pre-receive: expr: not found

Tags: git

I host git on my server and have webhooks that run commands like

```
branch=$(expr "$refname" : "refs/heads/\(.*\)")
```

This works perfectly with SSH git pushes but when trying to use the HTTPS protocol I get the error

```
hooks/pre-receive: expr: not found
```

I guess this is because the script runs as www-data when using https.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: `expr` is a standard UNIX tool. It should be available to all users, regardless of their permissions, unless a framework like SELinux is allowing only whitelisted executables to be run or the user's PATH doesn't include standard locations.

Comment: That said -- what's the shell being used to interpret this script? If it's bash (script starting with `#!/bin/bash`, not `#!/bin/sh`), you can replace this use of `expr` with builtins.

Comment: You might also look into setting PATH to explicitly include `/bin`, `/usr/bin`, or wherever else your `expr` binary is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is the same server, you should check that the `PATH` environment variable is set appropriately when this hook is invoked from your HTTP server; it's likely to be missing `/bin` or `/usr/bin` (whichever stores your `expr` command).

---

That said, there's no need for `expr` here at all. Assuming that the value in `$refname` starts with `refs/heads`:

```
# Delete the leading refs/heads/ from refname to get branch
branch=${refname#refs/heads/}
```

Otherwise:

```
# Delete everything up to and including the first instance of refs/heads/
branch=${refname#*refs/heads/}
```

If you want to check whether `refname` contains `refs/heads/` at all, this is most easily done in bash (your script starting with `#!/bin/bash`):

```
if [[ $refname = *refs/heads/ ]]; then
  branch=${refname#*/refs/heads/}
else
  # refname does not match the pattern
  branch=
fi
```

If you are in fact using bash, you can actually use even more similar code:

```
refname_re='refs/heads/(.*)'
if [[ $refname =~ $refname_re ]]; then
  branch=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I should have mentioned that I call other commands in the same script that are not working (likely due to the same issue). So refactoring would be useful but I need to solve the problem at hand.

Comment: How does one go about changing the path for www-data? Nginx btw.

Comment: One line at the top of the script (albeit below the shebang): `export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin`. The `export` itself is _usually_ unneeded (most likely, PATH is already in the environment), but this is a potentially exceptional situation.

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't understand correctly. Thanks for your help. 

I currently have #!/bin/sh I will have a play with that.

Comment: I strongly suggest changing your shebang (the `#!/bin/sh` line) to `#!/bin/bash` to enable the refactorings I describe in the answer as bash-only. Setting the PATH should go _immediately below_ that line.

Comment: Aha, you replyed with more information before my last post. Thanks.